# Pointer & template class

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

**Description:**
I was trying to create a class object based on the user input. I tried to store its reference with a pointer and use it at a later stage. A similar idea with the variable type `late` in Dart language. Is it possible to have this operation in CPP and if so, what kind of variable type should I use?

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class foo {
    public:
        T item;
        foo(){}
};

class bar_1 {
    public:
        int value = 99;
        void randomise();
};

class bar_2{
    public:
        string value = "init";
        void randomise();
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    void* ptr;
    if (i > 0) {
        ptr = new foo<bar_1>;
    }
    else {
        ptr = new foo<bar_2>;
    }

    // maybe run the function to randomise 'value'
    // ptr->item.randomise();
    cout << ptr->item.value;
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:**

```
cout << ptr->item.value;
|          ^~
error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
```

**Edit 1:** I am not allowed to modify the class bar atm, aschepler’s #1 solution fits the best.

**Edit 2:** I am revisiting this problem. I found the most straightforward method is to dump using a template and convert them into a class hierarchy structure, with 'bar 1' and 'bar 2' being the offspring classes of 'foo'. So, if a pointer to class 'foo' exists in the scope, it may be assigned as a pointer to either a 'bar 1' or a 'bar 2' object.

**Updated code: (class hierarchy)**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class foo {
public:
    // common function going to be overrided by children classes
    virtual void randomize() {
    }
};

class bar_1: public foo {
public:
    int value = 99;
    // bar_1 version of randomize()
    void randomize() override {
        cout << "Turning int from " << value << " to a new int\n";
        value++; // increment by 1
    }
};

class bar_2: public foo {
public:
    std::string value = "something";
    // bar_2 version of randomize()
    void randomize() override {
        cout << "Turning string from " << value << " to a new string\n";
        value = "new thing"; // diff string
    }
};

int main()
{
    int type = 1; // e.g type can variate from 1 to 10
    foo* ptr;
    switch(type)
    {
        case 1:
            ptr = new bar_1();
            break;
        case 2:
            ptr = new bar_2();
            break;
        // case 3:
        //     ...
        default:
            cout << "Invalid type\n";
            break;
    }
    ptr->randomize();
    return 0;
}
```

**Updated code: (keep using template class)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <optional>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class foo {
    public:
        T item; // an object either bar_1 or bar_2
        foo(T _item) : item(_item) {} // constructor assigning in-class variable "item"
        T getItem() // template function returning the in-class variable item
        {
            return item;
        }
};

class bar_1 {
    public:
        int value = 99;
};

class bar_2{
    public:
        string value = "str";
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0; // some value
    optional<variant<foo<bar_1>, foo<bar_2>>> foo_foo;
    if (i > 0) {
        foo_foo = foo(bar_1());
    }
    if (i < 0) {
        foo_foo = foo(bar_2());
    }
    // using visit
    // if i > 0, it gives 99 as foo.item has type bar_1, which has an int value 99
    // if i < 0, it gives "str" as foo.item has type bar_2, which has an string value "str"
    // if i == 0, it gives 0 as the optioanl variable foo_foo contains no values
    visit([](auto &_foo) { cout << _foo.getItem().value; }, *foo_foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `void*` part of this isn't the biggest problem. No matter which object is created, it is long-expired and destroyed by the time you reach the point where you're trying to deref that pointer. In both cases you (a) create the object, (b) capture it's address, (c) the object is destroyed, and then your code tries to utilize the now-destroyed 'thing'.

Comment: This is not how the C++ language works... **Read a few books** to familiarize yourself with C++. Or use other languages or technics...

Comment: From aschepler’s answer, using `variant` with `visit` is something I totally forgot about. It can be used if you know all the classes in advance, and doesn’t need any changes to the classes themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not in the way dynamic languages like JS and (AFAIK) Dart allow.

C++ is statically typed, so by the time you write `cout << ptr->item.value` in a (non-template) function, the types of `item` and `value` must be known. No way conflating unrelated types like `int` and `string` at runtime.

However, you may be able to use inheritance to achieve desired effect. A pointer to an object may always be converted to a pointer to its (accessible, i.e. `public` in most cases) base, and accessed like that base—but the object will retain its actual type, and all *virtual* methods of `base` will act on that type, and can be overriden:

```
class foo {
public:
    virtual ~foo() = default; // optional but highly recommended
    virtual randomize() {
        // the default implementation
    }
    // or: virtual randomize() = 0; // if you want ALL subclasses to override it
};

class bar_1: public foo {
public:
    int value = 99;
    void randomize() override {
        // the bar_1-specific implementation
    }
};

class bar_2: public foo {
public:
    std::string value = "something";
    void randomize() override {
        // the bar_2-specific implementation
    }
};

...

foo *obj = new bar_1(); // create an object of type bar_1, but treat it as foo
obj->randomize(); // will call bar_1::randomize as obj points to an object of type bar_1
// obj->value = 42; // won’t work: value is not a member of foo
delete obj;

obj = new bar_2(); // now, create an object of type bar_2, but treat it as foo again
obj->randomize(); // will call bar_2::randomize as obj now points to an object of type bar_2
delete obj;
```

Or with smart pointers (highly recommended):

```
std::unique_ptr<foo> obj = std::make_unique<bar_1>()
// std::unique_ptr<foo> obj{new bar_1()}; // if you can’t afford C++17
obj->randomize();

obj = std::make_unique<bar_2>();
// obj.reset(new bar_2()); // if you can’t afford C++17
obj->randomize();
```

Answer (score 1):

As comments have pointed out, you can't use a pointer to a variable declared in a block after the end of that block. You could fix this with a `std::unique_ptr`, or possibly `std::optional`.

Here are two possible solutions.

#1: A `std::variant<foo<bar_1>, foo<bar_2>>` can hold an object of either type, without requiring any changes to your existing classes (and without requiring any dynamic allocations). Then we can use `std::visit` to do things on whichever object it contains.

```
#include <variant>
#include <optional>
int main()
{
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    std::optional<std::variant<foo<bar_1>, foo<bar_2>>> the_foo;
    if (i > 0) {
        the_foo = foo<bar_1>{};
    }
    else {
        the_foo = foo<bar_2>{};
    }

    // run the function to randomise 'value'
    std::visit([](auto &foo) { foo.item.randomise(); }, *the_foo);
    std::visit([](auto &foo) { std::cout << foo.item.value; }, *the_foo);
    return 0;
}
```

#2 If you can change the classes, notice that `bar_1` and `bar_2` both contain some common operations "randomise item" and "print item". So we can create an interface allowing polymorphic use of those operations without knowing the actual type. This is also more easily extensible if you add additional similar classes later.

```
class IBar {
public:
    virtual ~IBar() = default;
    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
    virtual void randomise() = 0;
};

class bar_1 : public IBar {
public:
    int value;

    void print(std::ostream& os) const override
    { os << value; }

    void randomise() override;
};

class bar_2 : public IBar {
public:
    std::string value;

    void print(std::ostream& os) const override
    { os << value; }

    void randomise() override;
};
```

Now `foo` doesn't even need to be a template. It can just use an interface pointer instead of a member of the actual type:

```
#include <memory>
class foo {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<IBar> pItem;
    explicit foo(std::unique_ptr<IBar> p) : pItem(std::move(p)) {}
    foo() = default;
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    foo the_foo;
    if (i > 0) {
        the_foo.pItem = std::make_unique<foo<bar_1>>();
    }
    else {
        the_foo.pItem = std::make_unique<foo<bar_2>>();
    }

    // run the function to randomise 'value'
    the_foo.pItem->randomise();
    the_foo.pItem->print(std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```